# How to write a method trailing with a keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a situation where i need to call something like this :

```
class Office
   attr_accessor :workers, :id

   def initialize
      @workers = []
   end

   def workers<<(worker)
      type = worker.type
      resp = Organiation::Worker.post("/office/#{@id}/workers.json", :worker => {:type => type})
   end
end
```

this is where i need to call

```
office = Office.new()

new_worker = Worker.new()

office.workers << new_worker
```

how should i modify the above workers method in order to implement above code.

Comment: Are you using a framework? e.g. Rails?

Comment: @Ant: I am not using rails its in gem

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your new information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New answer for this (based on updated question):

```
class WorkersClient
  attr_accessor :office_id

  def <<(worker)
    type = worker.type
    resp = Organiation::Worker.post("/office/#{@office_id}/workers.json", :worker => {:type => type})
  end
end

class Office
  attr_accessor :workers, :id

  def initialize
    @workers = WorkersClient.new
    @workers.office_id = @id
  end
end
```

I'm assuming that the `Worker` class is defined somewhere, something like:

```
def Worker
  attr_accessor :type
  ...
end
```

The `WorkersClient` class is just a proxy to handle the collection (like ActiveRecord 3 does with associations). You can develop it further to store a local cache of workers, and so on.

I would recommend looking at how Rails' ActiveResource is implemented, as it does something VERY similar.

Comment: @Jits: but how can i access the id of office object in WorkersClient class ??

Comment: Interesting idea, but this doesn't work for `office.workers << worker`.

Comment: @MarkThomas, have you tried it? What error message do you get?

Comment: @Jits, the WorkersClient is not involved in that scenario.

Comment: @MarkThomas, the `WorkersClient` is just a proxy to handle the collection (like ActiveRecord 3 does with associations). I'm assuming that the `Worker` class has already been defined somewhere.

Comment: @Jits. Oh, I see. The WorkersClient object receives the << method and posts. Clever solution, +1.

Comment: @Jits, Your way was working but mine situation is bit complex. so according to your answer i have another question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248266/problem-supporting-two-way-syntax-in-ruby please go through this.

Comment: @ManishDas, I won't be going through anything else until you start upvoting and marking things as right answers :)

Answer (score 3):

try this `office.build_worker`

Comment: @sadikha: I have to implement on gem so no database stuffs.. any idea how to do this??

Comment: @mark: u should see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82003/how-to-see-who-updownvoted no hard feelings :)

Answer (score 0):

If those objects are actually ActiveRecord objects (which it sort of sounds like), you're probably looking at

```
office.workers << new_worker
```

Note the plural form.

If those objects are your own creations, you probably want Office#workers to return an Array'ish object, so something like

```
class Office
  def workers
    @workers ||= []
  end
end
```

Add sanity checks and whatnot as you see fit.

Comment: i can i do something like this :

Comment: Clarified the code example to make it obvious that the workers methods is meant to be in the Office class.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to add to what's already been said, but one thing to think about is hiding the implementation of `workers`. Sure, it starts out with an array, but that may change. By implementing your own `<<` method you can hide implementation details from the user.

```
class Office
  attr_accessor :workers

  def initialize
    @workers = []
  end

  def <<(other)
    self.workers << other
  end
end
```

I tend to use getter/setters inside my classes as that's something I learned from Smalltalk books, but of course you could just do `@workers << other`.