# Problem Supporting two way syntax in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a situation where i need to call something like this :

```
class Office

  attr_accessor :workers, :id

  def initialize
    @workers = []
  end

  def workers worker
    type = worker.type
    resp = Worker.post("/office/#{@id}/workers.json", :worker => {:type => type})
    worker = Worker.new()
    resp.to_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
      worker.send("#{k}=",v) if worker.respond_to?(k)
    end
    self.workers << worker
  end

end
```

Worker class

```
class Worker
  attr_accessor :office_id, :type, :id

  def initialize(options={})
    @office_id = options[:office].nil? ? nil : options[:office].id
    @type = options[:type].nil? ? nil : options[:type].camelize
    if !@office_id.nil?
       resp = self.class.post("/office/#{@office_id}/workers.json", :worker => {:type => @type})
       @id = resp.id
       office = options[:office]
       office.workers = self
    end
  end

  def <<(worker)
    if worker
      type = worker.type
      resp = Worker.post("/office/#{office_id}/workers.json", :worker => {:type => type})
      debugger
      @id = resp.id
      resp.to_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
        self.send("#{k}=",v) if self.respond_to?(k)
      end
      debugger
      return self
    end
  end
```

I can do something like this very well

```
office = Office.new()
new_worker = Worker.new()
office.workers new_worker
```

But i need to do same what i have done above like the following. Before that, i need to change the initialize method of Office to fire up the `def <<(worker)` method of the worker instance.

```
class Office
  ...
  def initialize
    @workers = Worker.new
    @workers.office_id = self.id
  end


office = Office.new()
new_worker = Worker.new()
office.workers << new_worker
```

Now the problem is, the later implementation creates 2 instances of the worker??

Comment: @zabba, it adds new worker object within worker attributes of office object and the worker attribute is an array.

Comment: Did you change more of the code than just that? As it is, office.workers << new_worker should be an ArgumentError since office.workers is a method taking 1 parameter.

Comment: @James, no that part is fine.

Comment: btw, "if !worker.nil?" is better expressed as "if worker"

Comment: @james, yeah but thats not the problem

Comment: i know, but i was just pointing it out.

Comment: hmmm..... good point though, i have updated

Comment: The code at the end **must** throw an ArgumentError. Your call is equivalent to office.workers().<<(new_worker). Since you overwrote the workers attribute accessor with a custom workers method that takes a **mandatory** argument worker, this call must fail. I'd bet something is wrong or missing in your code samples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I suppose you'd like to have this:

```
class Office

  attr_accessor :workers, :id

  def initialize
    @workers = []
  end

  alias_method :workers, :return_worker_array

  def workers worker
    unless worker
      return_worker_array
    else
      type = worker.type
      resp = Worker.post("/office/#{@id}/workers.json", :worker => {:type => type})
      worker = Worker.new()
      resp.to_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
      worker.send("#{k}=",v) if worker.respond_to?(k)
      return_worker_array << worker
  end
end
```

end

This way you can get rid of `Worker#<<` entirely and you should also remove the line

```
office.workers = self
```

in `Worker#initialize` since `office.workers` is supposed to be an array. It's a bad idea to change the type of an attribute (duck-typing would be OK) back and forth because it's likely you lose track of the current state and you will run into errors sooner or later.

To follow "Separation of Concerns", I would recommend to do the entire management of `workers` solely in `Office`, otherwise it gets too confusing too quickly and will be much harder to maintain on the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain why you aren't getting an error here, but since Office#workers last line is self.workers << worker, you are adding the new worker created in Office#workers (made on the 3rd line of the method), and then returning the workers object, which then gets #<< called again on it with the new worker created outside of the method

Comment: yeah thats why its messed up in order to implement that .... so any idea how i can implement #<< method when i call `office.workers << new_worker` as i have done in `office.workers new_worker`

Comment: i'd choose a different name for the attribute so you can do `office.workers new_worker` and `office.new_worker_name << new_worker`. Ideally, i would have chosen `office.add_worker new_worker` and `office.workers << new_worker`, but it seems you have legacy code to support so you don't want to change the previous calls. (I know this isn't what you asked for, but that's how i would do this. If you explained the scenario better, i might be able to give a different answer)

Comment: I just want same functioning for the later method as i have done in previous one and with same name. when i call `office.workers << new_worker` it simply calls the default getter/setter of workers attribute.